# RegExp range of number (1 to 36)

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched a lot and can't find the solution for this RegExp (I have to say I'm not very experienced in Reg. Expressions).

I would like to test a number between 1 and 36, excluding 0 and 37 and above.

What I've got so far and almost works (it doesn't accept 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29)...

```
^[1-9]{1}$|^[1-3]{1}[0-6]{1}$|^36$;
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You know about `\d`, right?

```
^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-6])$
```

Try this in console:

```
function test() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (/^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-6])$/.test(i.toString()) != (i >= 1 && i <=36)) {
            document.write(i + "fail");
        }
                else
                document.write(i + "pass");
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see `pass` for all values.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Use this

var pat = /^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (pat.test(i)) {
            document.write(i + "pass");
        }
        else {
                document.write(i + "fail");
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }

Answer (score 20):

`^(?:[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])$`

Here's a breakdown of it:

`^` = Start of line

`(?:` and `)` demark a non-capturing group- a way to specify order of operations without saving the matched contents for later.

`[1-9]` = any digit from 1-9

`|` = OR

`[1-2][0-9]` = '1' or '2', followed by any digit from 0-9

`|` = OR

`3[0-6]` = '3', followed by any digit from 0-6.

`$` = end of line

As @mu is too short said, using an integer comparison would be a lot easier, and more efficient. Here's an example function:

```
function IsInRange(number)
{
    return number > 0 && number < 37;
}
```

Comment: thnaks for the explanation, I really needed it to be a regexp, otherwise I would have solved it with plain old javascript :)

Comment: This solution incorrectly matches all numbers, as shown in [this demo forked from qwerymk's demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ua095dc/1/) and explained in @mickmackusa's answer.

Comment: @FWDekker Thank you, I believe I've fixed it now. Needed parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-6]$
```

(All 1 digit numbers between 1 and 9, all 1x and 2x numbers, and 3x numbers from 30 to 36).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why all of the answers to this repeat the mistake of adding boundaries (`^` and `$`) before and after each condition. But you only need to do:

```
^([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])$
```

I also created a JavaScript/Node.js library, [to-regex-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range), to simplify creating ranges like this.

Comment: This solution incorrectly matches 37, 38, 39, 40, as shown in [this demo forked from qwerymk's demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pwcqhez6/1/) and explained in @mickmackusa's answer.

Comment: It was missing parentheses. Fixed. FWIW your comment resulted in 4 downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I'm not sure what you mean by "repeat the mistake of adding boundaries before and after each condition" in your answer. Isn't that exactly what was missing in your answer before you corrected it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SdUmF/)

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$`

Answer (score 0):

Purely for academic reasons, I'll add a unique and accurate pattern.

```
/^(3[0-6]?|[12]\d?|[4-9])$/
```

There are three branches in the pattern:

1. The first matches: 3, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
2. The second matches: 1, 2, 10-19, 20-29
3. The third matches: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

If there is an efficiency advantage (not that this task is likely to be a major resource drain -- unless you are doing thousands of these evaluations) in my pattern, it will come down to the fact that there are no redundant checks in the pattern.

It may not make any difference to the regex engine, but I've ordered my branches based on the ones that take the least "effort" to evaluate (instead of the natural sequence of numbers).

Harpo's pattern is as brief as the pattern can be built, but `[123]` are first-digit matches that are satisfied by the multiple branches.

**@MichaelHoffmann's and @jonschlinkert's patterns are not correct because they fail to distribute the necessary anchors to each branch.**  This is concisely achieved by wrapping all branches in a capture group, but as @ninjalj, @qwertymk, and @amit_g demonstrated, it is just as accurate to apply the anchors to each branch.

```js
let txt = '<table border=1 cellpadding=4><tr><th>Number</th><th>Harpo</th><th>Michael Hoffmann</th><th>ninjalj</th><th>jonschlinkert</th><th>qwertymk</th><th>amit_g</th><th>mickmackusa</th></tr>',
    str,
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i <= 40; ++i) {
  str = '' + i;
  txt += '<tr><td>' + i;
  txt += '</td><td>'  + /^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-6])$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^[0-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-6]$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-6]$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6]$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td><td>' + /^(3[0-6]?|[12]\d?|[4-9])$/.test(str);
  txt += '</td></tr>';
}
txt = txt + '</table>';

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<div id="facts">Correct Pattern Designers: Harpo, ninjalj, qwertymk, amit_g, mickmackussa<br>Incorrect Patterns: Michael Hoffmann, jonschlinkert <br></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @jonschlinkert Please read my answer to understand why your pattern is incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann Please read my answer to understand why your pattern is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check run this in console Try this:

```
var pat = /^[1-9]$|^[1-2]\d$|^3[0-6]$/;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (pat.test(i)) {
            document.write(i + "pass");
        }
                else{
                document.write(i + "fail");}
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
```

(All digit numbers between 1 to 36).